# Multiplicative Variance Analysis

Tags: variance, data-analysis

I come from a math/stats background and as I learned some stuff as a data analyst
I learned some techniques that I have never seen academically and was hoping if anyone
has any knowledge of the following technique.

[image: Sample Table with Variance Calculation]

In this example, x drops 1.6% from period 1 to period 2.
The idea is to figure out how much each component contributes to this change
and as you can see the drop in the value of a is the driver of x dropping.

Any help is appreciated.